# What causes "Power-on or device reset occurred" when plugging USB mass storage device

Tags: kernel, usb

What causes "Power-on or device reset occurred" message on kernel log when plugging in an usb mass storage device? It seems to come from the SCSI subsystem, but the root cause isn't clear to me.

Context: I'm trying to use Raspberry PI Zero as a usb mass storage dev for a specific host. It works fine on several PCs but not on the embedded host. Trying to figure out what's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the embedded host was picky about partition table, the error mentioned in question might have been irrelevant to the issue. Issue was finally solved by removing the partition table completely and just using bare FAT32.